# Why did Galileo use a ramp instead of a rope/pulley in his famous experiment?

Tags: newtonian-gravity, acceleration, friction, history, experimental-technique

If I understand correctly, one can derive an equivalent relation between distance the body falls and time, by using a rope/pulley system too.

Conceptually it may be easier and perhaps more natural. The distance *fallen* would just be the length of the rope and things could be a lot easier to measure I believe.

So, what was the reason behind using a ramp? Is there a more physical consequence that isn’t immediately apparent? AFAIK, friction happens in both so that shouldn’t be a deciding factor. Or was it just *that’s how he thought and set it up*?

Comment: could you reference the famous experiment in question?

Comment: Amazon was running behind and he wouldn't get the low friction, high-speed bearings he'd ordered until Tuesday.

Comment: @dmckee They said they would arrive on Tuesday, but they never specified which year. That's how they getcha.